# Mostrar los registros de los últimos 3 meses

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

necesito mostrar los registros de los ultimos 3 meses, actualmente me muestra todos los registros hasta la fecha

este es mi código

```
public class listConsultaPropietarioRepository : Error
{
    public List<listaBusquedaPropietarioViewModel> getListaConsultaPropietario(DateTime? FECHA_DESDE, DateTime? FECHA_HASTA)
    {        
        List<listaBusquedaPropietarioViewModel> list = new List<listaBusquedaPropietarioViewModel>();

        this.clearError();

        try
        {
            using (var db = DAOEntities.obtenerEntities(SessionUsuario.Municipio))
            {

                DateTime? FECHA_HASTA_AUX = null;
                if (FECHA_HASTA.HasValue)
                {
                    DateTime fechax = FECHA_HASTA.Value;
                    FECHA_HASTA_AUX = new DateTime(fechax.Year, fechax.Month, fechax.Day, 23, 59, 59);
                }

                List<TABLA_SP_OBTENER_PERMISOS_RECEPCIONES_CERTIFICADOS> tablaSolicitud_certificado_Propietario = new List<TABLA_SP_OBTENER_PERMISOS_RECEPCIONES_CERTIFICADOS>();

                tablaSolicitud_certificado_Propietario = db.SP_OBTENER_PERMISOS_RECEPCIONES_CERTIFICADOS(SessionUsuario.IdUsuario).ToList<TABLA_SP_OBTENER_PERMISOS_RECEPCIONES_CERTIFICADOS>();

                tablaSolicitud_certificado_Propietario
                    .Where(
                            rr => (!FECHA_DESDE.HasValue || rr.FECHA_ESTADO >= FECHA_DESDE) &&
                            (!FECHA_HASTA_AUX.HasValue || rr.FECHA_ESTADO <= FECHA_HASTA_AUX)

                          )
                    .OrderByDescending(r => r.FECHA_ESTADO)
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(rr => list.Add(new listaBusquedaPropietarioViewModel
                    {  
                        NUMERO_SOLICITUD = rr.NUMERO_SOLICITUD,
                        ID_SOLICITUD = rr.ID_SOLICITUD,
                        //ID_CERTIFICADO = rr.ID_CERTIFICADO,
                        TIPO_FLUJO_SOLICITUD = rr.TIPO_FLUJO_SOLICITUD,
                        FECHA_ESTADO_SOLICITUD = (DateTime)rr.FECHA_ESTADO,
                        DIRECCION_SOLICITUD = rr.DIRECCION_SOLICITUD,
                        DESCRIPCION_TIPO_SOLICITUD_ABREVIADA = rr.DESCRIPCION_TIPO_SOLICITUD_ABREVIADA,
                        NEMONICO_TIPO_SOLICITUD = rr.NEMONICO_TIPO_SOLICITUD,
                        NUMERO_DIRECCION_SOLICITUD = rr.NUMERO_DIRECCION_SOLICITUD,
                        ID_TIPO_FORMULARIO_CERTIFICADO = rr.ID_TIPO_FORMULARIO_CERTIFICADO

                    }
            ));




            }
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.success = false;
            this.message = ex.Message;
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

lo resolvi con esta simple linea de codigo

```
int restaMes = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["restaMes"].ToString());



                    DateTime fechax = DateTime.Now;
                    var fechaMenosMes = new DateTime(fechax.Year, fechax.Month - restaMes, fechax.Day); 

                    FECHA_HASTA_AUX = DateTime.Now;
                    FECHA_DESDE = fechaMenosMes;
```

resta mes es 3